# swiper slider - swiping as one slide, but CSS is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

How come swiper slider is sliding all my divs as one? Did the library change?

Below is my example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    autoplay:false,
  direction: "horizontal",
    loop:false,
    pagination: {
        el: '.product-image-thumbs .swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        bulletActiveClass: 'active'
    }
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

you can see that all the slides are in one slide?

as per these answers

[Swiper Slider puts all slides in one slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997704/swiper-slider-puts-all-slides-in-one-slide)

[Swiper slider does not swipe slides on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664931/swiper-slider-does-not-swipe-slides-on-mobile-devices)

They all say to include the CSS file, but you can see that my CSS file is included, and the linked answers are now exhibiting the same behavior as mine.

Did swiper change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes might be links are outdated, refer [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/get-started/) for latest version and try this links:

```
// CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
// JS
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

There are few quick fixes:

- **Pagination:** Property `el` will allow comma separated classes, that you have separated with spaces
- **BulletActiveClass:** Currently there are no style on `active` class that you have specified, so commented for now
- **Script Location:** Always try to use scripts at the end of `body` tag, as i have add in below example
- **CSS**: I have added css from [swiper example](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/040-pagination-dynamic.html), because here without css slider was corrupted

Your working example with above fixes:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    autoplay:false,
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop:false,
    pagination: {
        el: '.product-image-thumbs, .swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        // bulletActiveClass: 'active'
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="product-image-thumbs"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```